# SQL Query complex tree join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a catalog that contains directories that can contain directories. The access of a directory can be granted to everyone or restricted to 0 to n user and/or to 0 to n usergroup. Access right is inherited in the hierarchy of group and from a group to its user. Therefore, a user can access a directory if he is allowed OR (he isn't deny AND (his group is allowed OR (his group isn't deny AND (his supergroup is allowed OR etc....

Their can be 1 to n level of groups, even if most of the time, their are typically no more than 3 levels.

I made a sqlfiddle from the schema : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81b28

What I need is to get the list directories inside a given directory that can be accessible by a given user.

What I have so far is the following: this get the content of directory id '3' accessible to the user id '10', who is in usergroup '3' which is in supergroup '1' :

```
select l.id, l.accessright, ll.parentlibrarydirectoryid, ulc.*, glc1.*, glc2.*
    from librarydirectory l
    inner join a_librarydirectory_librarydirectory ll on ll.childlibrarydirectoryid = l.id
    left join a_user_librarydirectory_canaccess ulc on ulc.librarydirectoryid = l.id
    left join ws_user u on u.id = ulc.userid
    left join a_group_librarydirectory_canaccess glc1 on glc1.librarydirectoryid = l.id
    left join a_group_librarydirectory_canaccess glc2 on glc2.librarydirectoryid = l.id
where 
    ll.parentlibrarydirectoryid = 3
    and (u.id = 10 or u.id is null)
    and (glc1.groupid = 3 or glc1.groupid is null)
    and (glc2.groupid = 1 or glc2.groupid is null)
    and (l.accessright = "n"
        or ((ulc.canaccess = "y") 
            or (ulc.canaccess is null and (glc1.allowedToAccess = 1 
            or (glc1.allowedToAccess is null and (glc2.allowedToAccess = 1))))));
```

It is working but I feel that this is not very elegant because I need to query the database to get the hierarchy of group prior to dynamically build the query in order to add as many a_group_librarydirectory_canaccess join and where clause as there are levels in the group hierarchy.

Is there a smarter way?

Thank you for your time

Comment: [Related question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7147). Unfortunately, the smarter way (recursive queries) supported by most databases isn't supported by MySQL.

Comment: @hvd thank you for the related question link. Will definitively help. Another option might be denormalization, by copying inherited rights from group to subgroups. Both are their pros & cons I guess. Thanks.